# Images on aspx pages with Master Page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, image

I have one master page, in short there are two images on the master page (a logo at the top, and a fb link at the bottom).

I do however have an admin folder for the .aspx pages for when admin log in.

All non-admin pages need to access these two images with the src of image/logo.jpg and image/fb.jpg. However the admin pages need to access the image with the src of /image/logo.jpg and /image/fb.jpg.

Is it possible to achieve two separate paths depending on the folder, without having to create a second master page?

Comment: Use ~/ at the start of image path, this resolves to site root wherever you are

Comment: the images for the admin are not in it's route, but back one

Comment: Correct, so ~/images/image.jpg will render correctly from root(AKA ~)/mainpage.aspx, ~/admin/admin.aspx, and as deep as you want.  Keep in mind this will only work on server controls, so if you want to use it in a normal HTML <img> control, you'll need to add a runat="server" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/images/yourimage.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use Image Server control instead of html img tag or ResolveUrl method to handle generated url:

```
<img src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/yourimage.png") %>' />
```